# Big-O notation: Prove that $3^x$ is $O(3^x - 2^x)$

Tags: notation, asymptotics

I have to show that $3^x$ is $O(3^x - 2^x)$. I'm just starting to learn the basics of Big-Oh notation. I'm thinking you have to take logarithms here, but am stuck on how to show this is true once I get $log(3^x-2^x)$ (although it makes intuitive sense to me that this is true). Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Consider $$\frac{3^x}{3^x-2^x}.$$

Comment: What is that limit?

Comment: How would I compute that limit? Taking the log of the numerator and denominator, I get $xlog(3)$ in the numerator but don't know what to do with $log(3^x-2^x)$ in the denominator.

Comment: @bob You don't have to find the limit (there doesn't even have to be a limit for big-$O$ to make sense). You just have to show that that that fraction is (for large enough $x$) bounded both below and above by positive numbers.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. But I'm still struggling to see what you can do to that fraction to show it is bounded. When graphing it, I see that it is clearly bounded above by 2 for x-large, but how would I go about showing this?

Comment: A general tip: logarithms do not play well with sums. There is no good way to handle $\log(a+b)$ or $\log(a-b)$ (unless you can do something about $a\pm b$ itself first).

Comment: Got it, good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the fraction $\frac{3^x}{3^x-2^x}$. Clearly, for $x>0$, this fraction is larger than $1$ (the numerator is larger than the denominator), so it is bounded below. Not that this is actually necessary for $3^x=O(3^x-2^x)$.

For bounded above, which *is* necessary, consider $x>1$. Note that $2^x<2\cdot 3^{x-1}$. This gives
$$
\frac{3^x}{3^x-2^x}<\frac{3^x}{3^x-2\cdot 3^{x-1}}=\frac3{3-2}
$$
So the fraction is bounded above, and we're done.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for clarifying!